# Select the first row in a group but in concurrent environment

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have multiple processes of the same application running at the same time as each other. Each of these processes performs some computations.

I have a "tests" table that looks like this:

```
 id | a | b |      c
----+---+---+-------------
 1  | a | b | Helloooo!!!
 2  | a | b | Helloooo...
 3  | c | d | World!!!
 4  | c | d | World...
```

Each process needs to retrieve the first row in a group (group by columns "a" and "b") from the table "tests" to perform some computations over it but one process shouldn't be able to select the row that has been already captured by another process. For example:

```
 id | a | b |      c
----+---+---+-------------
 1  | a | b | Helloooo!!!                  <------ Captured by process #1 and it won't have been available until the transaction is finished by process #1.
 2  | a | b | Helloooo...                  <------ Unavailable.
 3  | c | d | World!!!                     <------ Should be captured by concurrent process #2.
 4  | c | d | World...                     <------ Unavailable.
```

My SQL query without row-level locks:

```
WITH t AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a, b ORDER BY id ASC) AS rn
           FROM tests)
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

I tried to do something like this:

```
WITH groups AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a, b ORDER BY id ASC) AS rn FROM tests)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM groups WHERE rn = 1) subquery FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED LIMIT 1;
```

But both of the processes retrieves the same row (transactions are opened and aren't committed):

[image: Process #1]

- Process #1.

[image: Process #2]

- Process #2.

Comment: And the questions is? Doesn't your query work as expected?

Comment: You could use [`pg_advisory_lock()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS).

Comment: @jarlh I've added more details to the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `select...for update` targeted the temporary table resulting from your [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) rather than the `tests` table directly, misplacing the lock. If you instead `join` with that CTE to filter down records in the actual table that you target directly from the locking query, it'll lock `tests` table as expected:

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

WITH groups AS (
    SELECT  id, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER w1 AS rn 
    FROM tests
    window w1 as (PARTITION BY a, b ORDER BY id ASC))
SELECT * 
FROM tests inner join groups using (id) WHERE groups.rn = 1
FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED LIMIT 1;
```

Structuring the query the way you did would have worked if the `FOR UPDATE` was in the CTE that did target `tests` directly but the presence of a window function prevents that with the error `FOR UPDATE is not allowed with window functions` popping up whenever you try to combine these directly or through nesting in subqueries.

Comment: Thank you so much, you're absolutely right. That query works as expected!